# CPU utilisation reaches 100% on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on using normal application[VS Code] and browsers[Chrome/FF]

Tags: google-chrome, performance, disk-usage, cpu-load

The list of programs I generally run in parallel while facing 100% of CPU consumption are:

1. VS Code
2. Chrome [4-5 tabs]
3. Firefox [2-3 tabs]

On chrome, I normally take calls using GMeet which includes video/audio calls and sharing the screen as well. I am a software tester and usually while working on automation on VS Code and sharing any presentation neither I am able to run any automation script on VS Code nor navigate to other browser tabs or another browser [FF]. My entire OS freezes until I stop my video or close any of the browsers, or maybe sometimes close VS code as well!

I would appreciate any help from the group to check the problem and suggest any resolution on the same. I have shared my [configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwvug.png) with which things can be related. My laptop is dual-booted.

Comment: Since you have a dual boot installation, do you have the same issues while running VS code, chrome, and firefox when using your other operating system.

Comment: @mondotofu : Thanks for your reply. I haven't tried that as I don't prefer using Windows [My other OS on dual boot] for my day-to-day activities.

Comment: Though you have 32 GB of RAM, it could be that neither configuration can handle the amount of work you're attempting to do, so comparing them might provide some insights.  It's also possible that the web browsers are starting up trackers and other scripts that eat up your capacity.  I would recommend trying the brave browser (based on chromium) that blocks and secures your system better than those other browsers.

Comment: Just uninstalled Brave yesterday, it was utilizing most of my CPU! Chrome works well but the system still performs slow as soon as I run some automation from VS Code and do some presentations on google meet in parallel.

Comment: Have you considered running Wayland instead of X server? it reportedly has better ways of handling animations than the default X server.  Here's a link describing how to try it out:  https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/